# Bash Suppression Script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have the following script cleaning `egrep` arguments from all .csv files in current folders (used to clean email lists):

```
 #!/bin/bash
 for file in $(find . -name "*.csv" ); do
        echo "====================================================" >>  db_purge_log.txt
        echo "$file" >> db_purge_log.txt
        echo "----------------------------------------------------" >>  db_purge_log.txt
        echo "Contacts BEFORE purge:" >> db_purge_log.txt
        wc -l $file | cut -d " " -f1 >> db_purge_log.txt     
        echo " " >> db_purge_log.txt
        cat $file | egrep -v "marketing" | grep -v -E -i '([0-z])\1{2,}' | uniq | sort -u  > tmp_file 
        echo "$file is now clean!"
        mv tmp_file $file ; 
        echo "Contacts AFTER purge:" >> db_purge_log.txt
        wc -l $file | cut -d " " -f1 >> db_purge_log.txt  
done
```

I would like the `egrep -v "marketing"` section to be running in a loop on a file called `X.csv` and taking all the arguments from there. Eventually a list of around 6M contacts will be suppressed from another list of 6M contacts (need 6M*6M queries on the server if even possible).

Any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: So in place of `marketing`, you want to get the match string from the contents of a file? Use `egrep -v -f X.csv`.

Comment: [Don't iterate over the output of `find` with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: Hi, Not working. The idea is that in x.csv I have 3 email addresses (for example orr@wingate.com) => These 3 email addresses needs to be deleted from $file in my file above. changing to egrep -v -f x.csv doesn't do that.

Comment: Please show an example of the input and the expected output.

Comment: cat $file | egrep -v -f bounces.csv | grep -v -E -i '([0-z])\1{2,}' | uniq | sort -u  > tmp_file

Comment: bounce.csv contains 3 email addresses
$file stands for a .csv file in the folder with 3 matching email addresses (just create 2 files with the same 3 email addresses to purge each other)

Answer (score 0):

Note that your exclusion list will need to be one pattern (email address) per line, i.e. from the egrep man page:

-f FILE, --file=FILE
              Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line.  The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.

So modify your exclusion line as suggested by Orr, but, also make sure that your x.CSV file is really one email address per line. Also, this should most likely be case insensitive, so, perhaps something like:

```
cat $file | egrep -vi -f Excludes.txt | \  
    grep -v -E -i '([0-z])\1{2,}' | sort | uniq  > tmp_file
```

Based on experience, I prefer to use uniq AFTER sort.

:)
Dale